# Shopware6 : Key path "... / config / jwt / public.pem" permission error

Tags: shopware

After installation, I get below error message in browser

> Key path "... / config / jwt / public.pem" does not exist or is not
>   readable

After changing the permissions of public.pem to 660 or 600 error message changed to

> "not exist or not readable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preferred to solve it with ACL

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:r config/jwt/public.pem
setfacl -m u:www-data:r config/jwt/private.pem
```

Comment: Not solved Still Getting Error

Comment: not worknig, still getting the same error,

Answer (score 0):

If the marked answer doesn't solve the problem, there is a good chance that you do not have write access on the directory.

Before running the following command in your default directory, see if the mentioned files have a lock or an 'x' icon in the file explore.

if they do, run this command:

~$   sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME

Source that solved my exact error code: https://askubuntu.com/questions/263450/folders-showing-lock-icon